# How to write htaccess in this case

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(acp|acp/)$ /acp/home.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

But when i upload html file into root folder (example: ads.html) and run http://domain.com/ads.html it's not work, how to fix it

Comment: no, return index.php/ads

Answer (score 0):

Conditions only work for the rule they appear before. Your conditions work for the rule that rewrites `acp` to `acp/home.html`. You want to move the conditions directly before the second rule. You would end up with:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(acp|acp/)$ /acp/home.html [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```